# Filtering rows based on column values using dplyr

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, group-by

just a follow-up question from a previous thread, with previous help, using `group_by` and `filter` allowed me to only return countries that both have Import and Export values and view them separately. However, I realised now that I need to return rows based on an additional condition where the Species must also have fulfilled the Import & Export conditions.

For example, the string should only return rows belonging to country C as the species and country both meet the export & import condition. But I keep getting countries that fulfil the condition with species that do not meet the condition of having BOTH import and export.

```
Country Year    Quantity    Description Import/Export   Species
A   2001    10  Frozen  Export  X
B   2001    50  Fresh   Import  X
B   2004    20  Frozen  Export  Y
C   2003    30  Frozen  Import  X
C   2005    40  Fresh   Export  X
C   2006    60  Frozen  Import  X
D   2007    290 Fresh   Import  Y
```

Heres the Data for testing:

```
structure(list(Country = c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "D"), 
Year = c(2001, 2001, 2004, 2003, 2005, 2006, 2007), Quantity = c(10, 
50, 20, 30, 40, 60, 290), Description = c("Frozen", "Fresh", 
"Frozen", "Frozen", "Fresh", "Frozen", "Fresh"), `Import/Export` = c("Export", 
"Import", "Export", "Import", "Export", "Import", "Import"
), Species = c("X", "X", "Y", "X", "X", "X", "Y")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Link to previous thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69143212/how-do-i-filter-rows-based-on-two-values-within-a-column/69143265?noredirect=1#comment122205944_69143265

Comment: If you run the code in your post it returns only rows with Country = 'C'. what is your expected output ?

Comment: @RonakShah Hi Ronak! That was actually the expected output, It worked on the 2nd try when I restarted RStudio... not sure why but I guess it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Grouping based on Country AND Species helped me get the answer, took a few tries but the dplyr string below works

df %>% group_by(Country,Species) %>% filter(all(c('Import', 'Export') %in% Import/Export)) %>% ungroup()